# Invisible UINavigationBar inside UITabBarController

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My VC stack goes `UITabBarController` -> `UINavigationControllers` -> `UIViewControllers for this tab`. I am using the UITabBarControllerDelegate's function:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, animationControllerForTransitionFrom fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    guard fromVC.childViewControllers.first is FirstTabViewController,
        toVC.childViewControllers.first is SecondTabViewController else { return nil }
    return self
}
```

I then extend `FirstTabViewController` with `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` and define its two delegate functions. For the original Transition, this should work.

`FirstTabViewController` has a clear `UINavigationBar` due to the creation of a custom search bar being too difficult for me to achieve inside a navigation bar, although being it is different from the `UINavigationBar` of the `SecondTabViewController` this shouldn't have any effect on the issue at hand. The `SecondTabViewController` has a Regular UINavigationBar with a white background.

So the problem, Whenever I assign the `tabBarController.delegate` to `FirstTabViewController` the animation transition doesn't end with the `UINavigationBar` of the `SecondTabViewController` being visible. The `UINavigationController` of the `SecondTabViewController` is equal to nil at this point even though the root view of that tab is a navigation controller which is definitely the initial view controller of the storyboard. I will keep digging, but is there a way for me to do this without hiding the navigation bar?

Here is a link to an example project with the same issue. Any help in the right direction would be great.

https://github.com/Sethmr/InvisibleNavBarTest

If I remove the `UINavigationControllers` from the individual tabs and have one on the outside, it fixes this issue. Would this be the correct setup for my project? I am hesitant to make this change because I am expected a new set of bugs to fix that way including trying to change the color of the status bar at runtime along with reading that it is a poor setup anyhow.

Thanks for your time, any help is appreciated!